# ComboBox WPF Databinding to a DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

Lets say I have one ComboBox and 2 TextBox items on my GUI. And I have one DataView with data (City, PostalCode, Street, ID). While initializing the whole thing I fill my DataView with some data :)

```
City 1, 11111, Street 1, 1
City 1, 22222, Street 2, 2
City 1, 33333, Street 3, 3
```

Now I want to bind this to my ComboBox. DataView is a Class Member called `m_dvAdresses`, but this code doesnt help:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=m_dvAdresses}"
SelectedValuePath="ID"
DisplayMemberPath="Street">
```

Also I want to have my 2 ComboBox items to show PostalCode and City, depending on what to i pick in my ComboBox. Like if I pick "Street 2", TextBox1 show me "City 1" and TexBox2 show me "22222"...

How can I bind all of them ONLY in the WPF code?

Answer (score 2):

If `m_dvAddresses` is [a Field then WPF cannot bind to it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). WPF can only bind to CLR Properties and WPF `DependencyProperty`s.

```
public DataView Addresses
{
     get { return m_dvAddresses; }
}
```

<strike>As an aside, in order to get the richest WPF experience, consider making the collection type `ObservableCollection` (or some derivative of `IBindingList`). This way all changes to the collection itself are posted to the GUI appropriately.</strike> *Edit: I realize now that you're using `DataView` which is fully bindable.*

To answer your second question (given a `ComboBox` with `x:Name="Address"`):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.City, ElementName=Address}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Zip, ElementName=Address}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is have `m_dvAddresses` exposed as a property from your class as mentioned by @sixlettervariables. after that, to access it from XAML, you need to specify the `RelativeSource` property for the binding to point to the class itself as follows (here my control is a `Window`):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
Name="cmbAddresses"
```

For the text boxes, you have to specify their bindings as follows

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" 
         Text="{Binding SelectedItem.PostalCode, ElementName=cmbAddresses}"/>
```

similar for the second TextBox

Hope this helps :)